# JavaScript regex that ignores matches nested inside parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I use JavaScript to create a regular expression that finds all text in between comma delimiters, but ignores commas found inside nested parentheses?  For example, in the example subject below, I would hope to get exactly 3 matches:

Example Subject

```
one, two, start (a, b) end
```

Expected matches:

1. "one"
2. "two"
3. "start (a, b) end"

After spending nearly a full day trying (and failing) to figure this out, I remembered my old friend Stackoverflow.  Can anyone help?  Perhaps there are techniques aside from regular expressions that would be better suited for this task?

Comment: Why dont you think of using split based on comma?

Comment: Wouldn't you expect 4 matches, the fourth one being `""`, just like `str.split(',')` would do when faced with a trailing comma?

Comment: If you expect arbitrary expressions and nesting inside your commas, use a parser like Antlr. If you don't mind showing a complete specification and your attempt, the question could be answerable.

Comment: Thanks, @Mandy8055 - I did read that answer you posted previously, but couldn't see how to tailor it to my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own parser, and keep track of a "stack" to detect whether a parenthesis was opened before. The example below works with `()`, `[]`, `{}`, or anything you want. And they can be nested inside each other.

You can use it like so:

```
const mySplit = customSplitFactory({
  delimiter: ',',
  escapedPairs: {
    '(': ')',
    '{': '}',
    '[': ']'
  }
});

mySplit('one, two, start (a, b) end'); // ["one"," two"," start (a, b) end"]
```

Code & demo:

```js
// Generic factory function
function customSplitFactory({ delimiter, escapedPairs }) {
  const escapedStartChars = Object.keys(escapedPairs);

  return (str) => {
    const result = str.split('')
      // For each character
      .reduce((res, char) => {
        // If it's a start escape char `(`, `[`, ...
        if (escapedStartChars.includes(char)) {
          // Add the corresponding end char to the stack
          res.escapeStack.push(escapedPairs[char]);
          // Add the char to the current group
          res.currentGroup.push(char);
        // If it's the end escape char we were waiting for `)`, `]`, ...
        } else if (
          res.escapeStack.length &&
          char === res.escapeStack[res.escapeStack.length - 1]
        ) {
          // Remove it from the stack
          res.escapeStack.pop();
          // Add the char to the current group
          res.currentGroup.push(char);
        // If it's a delimiter and the escape stack is empty
        } else if (char === delimiter && !res.escapeStack.length) {
          if (res.currentGroup.length) {
            // Push the current group into the results
            res.groups.push(res.currentGroup.join(''));
          }
          // Reset it
          res.currentGroup = [];
        } else {
          // Otherwise, just push the char into the current group
          res.currentGroup.push(char);
        }
        return res;
      }, {
        groups: [],
        currentGroup: [],
        escapeStack: []
      });
     
     // If the current group was not added to the results yet
     if (result.currentGroup.length) {
       result.groups.push(result.currentGroup.join(''));
     }
 
     return result.groups;
  };
}

// Usage

const mySplit = customSplitFactory({
  delimiter: ',',
  escapedPairs: {
    '(': ')',
    '{': '}',
    '[': ']'
  }
});

function demo(s) { // Just for this demo
  const res = mySplit(s);
  console.log([s, res].map(JSON.stringify).join(' // '));
}

demo('one, two, start (a, b) end,');   // ["one"," two"," start (a, b) end"]
demo('one, two, start {a, b} end');    // ["one"," two"," start {a, b} end"]
demo('one, two, start [{a, b}] end,'); // ["one"," two"," start [{a, b}] end"]
demo('one, two, start ((a, b)) end,'); // ["one"," two"," start ((a, b)) end"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As some comments suggested you can use the split function.
example:

```
let str = "one, two, start (a, b) end,";
let matches = str.split(/(?<!(\"|\{|\()[a-zA-Z0-9]*),(?![a-zA-Z0-9]*\)|\}|\")/);
```

matches is gonna be an array containing [
"one",
"two",
"start (a, b) end",
""
];

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, this still splits the string even with the comma nested inside the parenthesis.

Comment: I adjusted the answer to cover that case, though the resulting array will also contain the matching parameter so the comma.

Comment: I found the edited solution still doesn't provide a proper split.  The result of the split using your regex is an array containing one item.

Answer (score 1):

If unmatched braces don't need to be handled, this could be simplifed to a naive balanced brace counter.
Currently using default to normal text best effort:

- If a closing brace is detected, it will try to find the starting brace and enclose on it, treating enclosed segment as text
- If no starting brace found treat it like normal text

```js
const braces = {'{':'}','[':']','(':')'}
// create object map of ending braces to starting braces
const inv_braces = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(braces).map(x=>x.reverse()))
const red = new RegExp(`(,)|` +
  `([${Object.keys(braces).join('')}])|` + 
  `([${Object.values(braces).map(x=>`\\${x}`).join('')}])` , 'g')
  // pre-build break-point scanning regexes
  // group1 comma detection, group2 start braces, group3 end braces

element_extract= str => {
  let res = []
  let stack = [], next, last = -1
  
  // search until no more break-points found
  while(next = red.exec(str)) {
    const [,comma,begin,end] = next, {index} = next
    
    if(begin) stack.push(begin) // beginning brace, push to stack
    else if(end){ //ending brace, pop off stack to starting brace
      const start = stack.lastIndexOf(inv_braces[end])
      if(start!==-1) stack.length = start
    }
    else if(!stack.length && comma) res.push(str.slice(last+1,last=index))
    // empty stack and comma, slice string and push to results
  }
  if(last<str.length) res.push(str.slice(last+1)) // final element
  return res
}

data = [
"one, two, start (a, b) end",
"one, two, start ((a, (b][,c)]) ((d,e),f)) end, two",
"one, two ((a, (b,c)) ((d,e),f)) three, start (a, (b,c)) ((d,e),f) end, four",
"(a, (b,c)) ((d,e)],f))"
]
for(const x of data)
console.log(element_extract(x))
```

Notes:

- Escaping can be added by adding another match group for \ and incrementing index to skip
- Regex string sanitizer can be added to allow matching on special characters
- Second regex can be added to skip commas for optimization (see edit history)
- Support for variable length delimiters can be added by replacing comma matcher and including length of delimiter in calculations.  Same goes for braces.

  - For example, I could use (\s*,\s*) instead of (,) to strip spaces, or use '{{':'}}' as braces by adjusting the regex builder to use '|' instead of character classes

For simplicity I have left these out

Answer (score 1):

You need to thinking about special case first that is parentheses, handle it at first:

```
var str, mtc;
str = "one, two, start (a, b) end, hello";
mtc =  str.match(/[^,]*\([^\)]+\)[^,]+|[^,]+/g);
console.log(mtc);
//Expected output: ["one","two", " start (a, b) end", " hello"]
```

First thing, handle parentheses:

```
patt = /[^,]*\([^\)]+\)[^,]+/g
//That will match any character after ,
//Then match character "(" and then match any charecter with no ")" then ends with )

//Now is easy things, we just matches character withno colon
patt = /[^,]+/g
```