# Regex to replace the ',' between [ ] by '.'

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
string value = "1: [polo, pola, pilo], 2: [molo, mola, moli], 3: [colo, cola, coli]"
// result should be:  "1: [polo. pola. pilo], 2: [molo. mola], 3: [colo. cola. coli. colu]"
```

i want a regex to replace the ',' between [ ] by '.'
the output has to be like this

```
"1: [polo pola pilo], 2: [molo mola moli], 3: [colo cola coli]"

what i tried.

    const regex = /[,]\s\D/gm;
    
    result = result.replace(regex, "");

my regex is not good.
```

Comment: Great, what have you tried so far? Show us your attempts at solving the problem, and where *specifically* in those attempts you're getting stuck.

Comment: easiest solution: use a replacer function and two levels of regex replace

Comment: two levels of regex ?

Comment: Must use regex?
Why "."s?
Here's a way without regex:  
sss=s.split("], ").join("]").split(",").join(".").split("]").join("], ")  
first split removes the special "], " so the commas won't change, joining with only "]".  
second split removes the commas, joining with "." instead.  
third split re-places the saved with "]" with the original "], "....

Comment: assumes no nested brackets: `str.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, x=>x.replace(/,/g,'.'))`

Comment: actually if nested brackets aren't a concern this is good enough `value.replace(/,(?=[^[\]]*\])/g,'.')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace comma in parentheses using regex in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697139/replace-comma-in-parentheses-using-regex-in-java)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. you saved my life.. LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes you have no unmatched brackets, and no nested brackets.
Based on above assumptions:
If comma isn't followed by any brackets other than an ending bracket, it must be inside a bracket.

```js
value = "1: [polo, pola, pilo], 2: [molo, mola, moli], 3: [colo, cola, coli]"
console.log(
value.replace(/,(?=[^[\]]*\])/g,'.')
)
```

---

If you need to account for unmatched brackets:

```
value.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, x=>x.replace(/,/g,'.'))
```

First finds matching [ ] brackets, then replaces all commas in that string in the replacer function before returning the desired replacement string.

---

If you need nested brackets, you will need to use a stack:
[JavaScript regex that ignores matches nested inside parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490041/javascript-regex-that-ignores-matches-nested-inside-parentheses/)
Instead of ignoring enclosed strings, you'll want to adjust it to replace commas in the enclosures.  For my answer in there, it would be if stack.length > 0 and comma, replace with period.